# Binding DPDK to a NIC without loosing connection

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I want to bind DPDK to a NIC and I'm following this documentation [here](http://dpdk-guide.gitlab.io/dpdk-guide/setup/binding.html)
If I only have one physical NIC, how do we ensure that we don't loose connection to the machine while running the dpdk_nic_bind command?

More specifically, I have a Google compute VM on which I'm trying to do this, and obviously my SSH connection gets lost when I am at this step. What is the workaround for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup DPDK without loosing SSH connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/1565392/how-to-setup-dpdk-without-loosing-ssh-connection)

Answer (score 0):

There is direct no workaround for this. However, there are few options to run a DPDK app without using physical NICs:

### Running DPDK inside a Virtual Machine

1. Run a virtual machine with as many NICs as you need.
2. Inside Virtual Machine, bind NICs to UIO.
3. Inside Virtual Machine, run DPDK and it should work OK with NICs inside Virtual Machine.

For more information, please have a look at [DPDK Poll Mode Driver for Emulated Virtio NIC](https://dpdk.org/doc/guides/nics/virtio.html).

Please note, this option might not be available on VM, i.e. you might not be able to run a VM inside a VM.

### Using DPDK Virtual Device

1. Compile DPDK with `libpcap` support.
2. Configure host to run a DPDK app as usual (i.e. enable huge pages etc).
3. Do not bind any NICs to UIO.
4. Create few TUN/TAP interfaces, bridge them with a physical NIC.
5. Run a DPDK application as usual, but pass few `--vdev` arguments to create few Virtual Devices, for example:

   testpmd -l 0-3 -n 4 \
   --vdev 'net_pcap0,iface=tun0' --vdev 'net_pcap1,iface=tun1' ...

For more information, please have a look at [DPDK libpcap Poll Mode Driver](https://dpdk.org/doc/guides/nics/pcap_ring.html).

Please note, this options will significantly reduce DPDK performance due to use Linux kernel functionality and pcap library.

### Using NIC Virtual Functions:

1. Configure SR-IOV support on the host.
2. Configure few Virtual Functions on the host NIC.
3. On host, bind few NIV Virtual Functions to `vfio-pci`
4. On host, run DPDK and it should work OK with NIC Virtual Functions.

For general description of SR-IOV, you might find useful [DPDK Intel Virtual Function Driver](https://dpdk.org/doc/guides/nics/intel_vf.html).

Please note, this option might not be available on VM.

Answer (score 0):

With limited information on the actual scenario, I have to make some assumption from your problem description.

1. `you want to receive and transmit normally through a single interface inside VM while using for DPDK application`
2. `you do not want to create tap or vhost interface from the host and pass it through guest`

with these assumptions, my humble recommendation is to make use of XDP-BPF on your current interface to redirect selected or desired test traffic to AF-SOCK. Start DPDK 19.11.1 LTS to make use AF-XDP PMD in your desired DPDK application.

[EDIT-1] I have explained this with [use DPDK without loosing ssh](https://superuser.com/questions/1565392/how-to-setup-dpdk-without-loosing-ssh-connection/1565862#1565862)