# How to setup DPDK without loosing SSH connection?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh

A similar question has been asked before on this site [1] but it doesn't seems answer anything that's practical for my problem. Therefore, I decided to ask same question for my environment.

I'm using a Linode Ubuntu Server with a single NIC and attempted to intitlize DPDK yesterday, it did installed Kernel Driver and bined the NIC then cut me off from SSH. I was not able to reconnect since then and I went on and restarted the server, I was able get into server again.

My network device as shown from DPDK status output,

```
 dpdk-devbind -s

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:00:04.0 'Virtio network device 1000' if=eth0 drv=virtio-pci unused=vfio-pci *Active*
```

[1] [Binding DPDK to a NIC without loosing connection](https://superuser.com/questions/1204835/binding-dpdk-to-a-nic-without-loosing-connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `eth0` is the default and only interface, the current ssh is running over the same via Kernel. hence by removing the interface from kernel and binding to DPDk will lead to loss of connection.

As pointed out the answer `https://superuser.com/questions/1204835/binding-dpdk-to-a-nic-without-loosing-connection/1546752#1546752` there is are an option available

1. Create a virtual TAP interface inside VM
2. Create eBPF-XDP code which redirects desired packets to TAP interface via XDP-REDIRECT, while the rest of the packet kernel XDP-PASS
3. Using PCAP-PMD and eal-arg `--vdev=net_pcap0,iface=[virtual tap interface]`

other option is to

1. start DPDK application with `--vdev=net_tap0,iface=[DPDK tap interface name]`
2. then load eBPF-XDP which redirects desired packet to DPDK-TAP interface.

thus without losing any connection one can make use traffic coming from virtio.

note: the kernel should be build and support eBPF-XDP for virtio.

[EDIT-1]

1. reference code: modify `https://github.com/vipinpv85/DPDK-DDoS/blob/master/test/ebpf/l2_port_fwd.c` to suit to needs.
2. How to build: `https://github.com/vipinpv85/DPDK-DDoS/blob/master/README.md``